# Raspbian Buster and XRDP keyboard layout

Tags: raspbian, xrdp

I've Raspbian Buster installed on Raspberry Pi 4. I installed XRDP by first removing/purging RealVNC server (according to some sources on the web, they cannot coexist peacefully) and then installing XRDP itself. It works fine with an exception: on remote session i have wrong keyboard layout. It always defaults to US layout instead the one I need (Slovenian).
In the past I have used steps below to change default layout which worked for me OK on Jessie and Stretch, i.e:

```
sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-00000424.ini 
sudo mv km-0424.ini /etc/xrdp 
sudo
chown root:root /etc/xrdp/km-00000424.ini
sudo service xrdp restart
```

*km-00000424.ini is layout for Slovenian XRDP keyboard. Layout names for other languages can be found at https://sourceforge.net/p/rdesktop/code/1704/tree/rdesktop/trunk/doc/keymap-names.txt.*

Unfortunately the steps above are  not working for me on Buster/RPi4. I spent quite a lot of time trying to find possible solution but without success.

I think this can be due to some changes either in Buster or in current XRDP version (it is version 0.9.10). I wonder if there's anyone who knows how this should be done or at least who can point me somewhere where I can find current (not obsolete) info??

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've done it a few times on different systems and still do not remember the steps so I have to discover it again and again. So here it is. Besides your recipe,

```
sudo xrdp-genkeymap km-00000424.ini 
sudo mv km-00000424.ini /etc/xrdp         #minor typo corrected 
sudo
chown root:root /etc/xrdp/km-00000424.ini
```

just before you restart xrdp, you have to enter your kbd language to **xrdp_keyboard.ini** too :) :

```
sudo vi xrdp_keyboard.ini 
#under 3 sections should be added our new language as follows:
[default_rdp_layouts]
rdp_layout_si=0x00000424
#and
[default_layouts_map]
rdp_layout_si=si
#and 3rd one - if needed
[rdp_layouts_map_mac]
rdp_layout_si=si
```

If you have **si** as layout (check with **localectl**).

Now you can restart xrdp service or even have to reboot the system. Next time I'll be looking at my post here XD  ...